# Capella XHTML tables are not properly handled by M2Doc

Tags: m2doc

I am using tables in Capella descriptions and found out that M2Doc fails at handling properly merged cells.

Here is an example of what I have in a Capella description:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" dir="LTR" width="172">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" height="19" rowspan="2" width="50%">
        <p align="CENTER">test</p>
        </td>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">c</font></font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">d</font></font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">a</font></font></p>
        </td>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">e</font></font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">b</font></font></p>
        </td>
        <td height="19" width="50%">
        <p align="LEFT"><font face="Calibri" size="3"><font face="Calibri" size="3">f</font></font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Table in Capella](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdnZK.png)

The result in Word is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw865.png)

Is that a known bug? I have used an online editor ([link towards XHTML tool](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan)) to check the validity of the Capella XHTML code and it is valid. Therefore, I have the feeling it is the conversion to Word that is faulty.

Thank you very much,

Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Merged cells are supported by M2Doc:
https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/4cb5e1a2d852f1ec0e678906ae3bbcee791fa418/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/element/MTable.java#L169

But it is not used by the HTML service. I opened the following issue:
https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/460